# How to disable the thread list popup when hovering at the current statement indicator in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

This is the popup I mean:

[image]

It happens to obscure the indicator margin for a couple of lines, making it impossible to drag the current statement indicator to those lines.

Answer (score 2):

The "Debugging" toolbar has a button called "Show threads in source":

[image]

Turn it off to disable this pop-up, along with the messy-looking graphic underneath the current statement indicator:

[image]

(took me far too long to find this, and Googling didn't help, hence this answer... it doesn't help that this button cannot be found by searching for "thread"in the otherwise excellent Quick Launch search box)

Comment: After all those years, Google has brought me to your answer. :)